# Error con llave foranea en postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE auditoria (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    fechat timestamp without time zone DEFAULT ('now'::text)::timestamp(6)    
    with time zone NOT NULL,
    modulo character varying(30),
    accion character varying(11),
    fecha character varying(11),
    id_usuario integer NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.auditoria OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: equipo_jugador; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE equipo_jugador (
    id_equipo integer,
    id_jugador integer,
    incremento1 integer NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.equipo_jugador OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: equipo_jugador_incremento1_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE SEQUENCE equipo_jugador_incremento1_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.equipo_jugador_incremento1_seq OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: equipo_jugador_incremento1_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER SEQUENCE equipo_jugador_incremento1_seq OWNED BY equipo_jugador.incremento1;


--
-- Name: evaluacion; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE evaluacion (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nombre character varying(100),
    proposito character varying(100),
    tipo integer NOT NULL,
    id_pregun_respues integer NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.evaluacion OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: evaluacion_jugador; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE evaluacion_jugador (
    id_evaluacion integer NOT NULL,
    id_jugador integer NOT NULL,
    nota integer NOT NULL,
    consecutivo integer NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.evaluacion_jugador OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: evaluacion_jugador_consecutivo_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE SEQUENCE evaluacion_jugador_consecutivo_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.evaluacion_jugador_consecutivo_seq OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: evaluacion_jugador_consecutivo_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER SEQUENCE evaluacion_jugador_consecutivo_seq OWNED BY evaluacion_jugador.consecutivo;


--
-- Name: jugador; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE jugador (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nombre character varying(50),
    apellidos character varying(50),
    cedula integer NOT NULL,
    foto character varying(100),
    capitan integer NOT NULL,
    fecha_nac character varying(10),
    dorsal integer NOT NULL,
    estatus integer NOT NULL,
    sexo integer NOT NULL,
    id_equipo integer NOT NULL,
    id_usuario integer NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.jugador OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: jugador_evento; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE jugador_evento (
    id_evento integer,
    id_jugador integer,
    asistencia integer,
    gol integer,
    intercepcion integer,
    incremento integer NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.jugador_evento OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: jugador_evento_incremento_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE SEQUENCE jugador_evento_incremento_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.jugador_evento_incremento_seq OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: jugador_evento_incremento_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER SEQUENCE jugador_evento_incremento_seq OWNED BY jugador_evento.incremento;


--
-- Name: municipio; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE municipio (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nombre character varying(50)
);


ALTER TABLE public.municipio OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: parroquia; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE parroquia (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nombre character varying(50),
    id_municipio integer
);


ALTER TABLE public.parroquia OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: pregunta_respues; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE pregunta_respues (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    pregunta character varying(100),
    respuesta integer NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.pregunta_respues OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: usuario; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE usuario (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    login character varying(20),
    clave character varying(40),
    estatus integer,
    permiso integer
);


ALTER TABLE public.usuario OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: incremento1; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY equipo_jugador ALTER COLUMN incremento1 SET DEFAULT nextval('equipo_jugador_incremento1_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: consecutivo; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY evaluacion_jugador ALTER COLUMN consecutivo SET DEFAULT nextval('evaluacion_jugador_consecutivo_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: incremento; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY jugador_evento ALTER COLUMN incremento SET DEFAULT nextval('jugador_evento_incremento_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Data for Name: auditoria; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY auditoria (id, fechat, modulo, accion, fecha, id_usuario) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Data for Name: equipo_jugador; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY equipo_jugador (id_equipo, id_jugador, incremento1) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Name: equipo_jugador_incremento1_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('equipo_jugador_incremento1_seq', 1, false);


--
-- Data for Name: evaluacion; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY evaluacion (id, nombre, proposito, tipo, id_pregun_respues) FROM stdin;
123 camilo  jugar   234 567
126 camilo  jugar   234 22
128 camilo  jugar   234 22
129 camilo  jugar   4   22
\.


--
-- Data for Name: evaluacion_jugador; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY evaluacion_jugador (id_evaluacion, id_jugador, nota, consecutivo) FROM stdin;
123 234 567 1
\.


--
-- Name: evaluacion_jugador_consecutivo_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('evaluacion_jugador_consecutivo_seq', 1, true);


--
-- Data for Name: jugador; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY jugador (id, nombre, apellidos, cedula, foto, capitan, fecha_nac, dorsal, estatus, sexo, id_equipo, id_usuario) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Data for Name: jugador_evento; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY jugador_evento (id_evento, id_jugador, asistencia, gol, intercepcion, incremento) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Name: jugador_evento_incremento_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('jugador_evento_incremento_seq', 1, false);


--
-- Data for Name: municipio; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY municipio (id, nombre) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Data for Name: parroquia; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY parroquia (id, nombre, id_municipio) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Data for Name: pregunta_respues; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY pregunta_respues (id, pregunta, respuesta) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Data for Name: usuario; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY usuario (id, login, clave, estatus, permiso) FROM stdin;
\.


--
-- Name: auditoria_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY auditoria
    ADD CONSTRAINT auditoria_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: equipo_jugador_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY equipo_jugador
    ADD CONSTRAINT equipo_jugador_pkey PRIMARY KEY (incremento1);


--
-- Name: evaluacion_jugador_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY evaluacion_jugador
    ADD CONSTRAINT evaluacion_jugador_pkey PRIMARY KEY (consecutivo);


--
-- Name: evaluacion_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY evaluacion
    ADD CONSTRAINT evaluacion_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: jugador_evento_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY jugador_evento
    ADD CONSTRAINT jugador_evento_pkey PRIMARY KEY (incremento);


--
-- Name: jugador_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY jugador
    ADD CONSTRAINT jugador_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: municipio_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY municipio
    ADD CONSTRAINT municipio_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: parroquia_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY parroquia
    ADD CONSTRAINT parroquia_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: pregunta_respues_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY pregunta_respues
    ADD CONSTRAINT pregunta_respues_pkey
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando intento ingresar datos a la tablas me sale este error y no entiendo todo deberia ir bien ya que estan bien declaradas las llaves foraneas

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿no te falta `PRIMARY KEY (id);` en la acción del `ADD CONSTRAINT` en tu última línea de código?